# How can I add the values from my NSTextFields in core data programmatically on button click?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have simple entity named People with 2 attributes, name(string) and birthDate(date).

Here is my AppDelegate.h file (just the method that I created, I have omitted the boilerplate code):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *nameTextField;
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *birthDateTextField;
    - (IBAction)saveButtonHasBeenClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is the AppDelegate.m file

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonHasBeenClicked:(id)sender {
    //NSLog(@"Name value is: %@", _nameTextField.stringValue);
    //NSLog(@"Birth Date value is: %@", _birthDateTextField.stringValue);
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];    
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how should I proceed to save the user entered values when button is clicked?

Comment: I recommend you to familiarize with MagicalRecord framework. Its so conveniently to work with Core Data, also you can see under the hood and check it. Good luck!

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko whether MR is good or not doesn't matter, because it's irrelevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedure is as follow get or create object in core data then call save. Assuming you are creating new user it would be:

```
// Create new person
Person *person = NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:"Person"
                  inManagedObjectContext:_context];
// Apply attributes
person.name = nameField.text;

// Save new record
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
}
```

If you have the person already as record you fetch it instead of creating new.

Have a look at some tutorial on CoreData: this one really nice  https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/full-core-data-application/